# Dimension of Image of Linear Transformation and their compositions

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a linear space of dimension 10 and $L : V \to V$ a linear transformation. Can (8,6,4) be the dimensions of $L(V), L^2(V)$ and $L^3(V)$ respectively?

Comment: Yes, Pick an ordered basis and consider the linear map mapping the frist two basis vectors to zero, and cycles the rest of the basis vectors by adding 2 mod 10. Then you g’et the desired dimensionality of your images.

Comment: Here's a different hint: Can you do - instead of $(10,8,6,4)$ - $(3,2,1,0)$? Then $(6,4,2,0)$? Can you do $(1,1,1,1)$? Can you now do $(7,5,3,1)$ etc ..

Comment: @LBE What's T(v_8)? according to your answer.

Comment: L(v_8)=v_0 which then gets killed off by the next iteration of the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about : Take $V=Span\{v_1,...,v_{10}\}$, and $L$ s.t. $L(v_1)=L(v_2)=0$ and $L(v_i)=v_{i-2}$ when $i\geq 3$.